# Refused to execute script because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, mime-types

I know there are already some other similar questions but nothing from there worked for me. I hope someone can provide feedback on this.

I have an html test page in my webapp where I'm using a JS file. It used to work but I had to make some changes to the JS file and now that I want to test it is giving that error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="my-file-sdk.js"></script>
</head>
```

My changes to the JS file are not the reason of the error, I even tried with the two previous versions and I got the same error.

The console also shows

```
GET https://localhost:44444/my-file-sdk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: a) very unusual to have `https` on `localhost`. b) is `my-file-sdk.js` in the "root" folder of the http server? 404 suggests not - and whatever your http server is seems to be sending html when there is a 404 error

Comment: Seems pretty clear cut, that file does not exist on the server, or no javascript is being returned from there.

Comment: @JaromandaX, it's located into root/src folder, I also tried putting the absolute path.
Yes, it is unusual; but I like to test my changes locally before to deploy them, and I do that by embedding my js file in the html page. The default test page functionality is to call the file deployed in Azure CDN

Comment: @Evert, thanks I will double check that.

Comment: by unusual I meant to say I didn't think it was possible to have `https://localhost` - anyway, whatever is serving the resources can't find the one you want